# Regular expression illegal character in Java

Tags: java, regex, illegal-characters

I've been looking through the Internet an after a big headache, cannon't find why this regular expression is wrong:

```
"\"\w*&&[\p{Punct}]\"["+sepChar+"]\"\w*&&[\p{Punct}]\""
```

I'm trying to read a master data file with the following pattern (quotes included):

```
"TEXTVALUE":"TEXTVALUE":"TEXTVALUE"
```

and split each line with the regular expression above.

So, for example:

```
"Hello:John":"Hello:World":"Hello:Mark"
```

will be splitted into:

```
{"Hello:John", "Hello:World", "Hello:Mark"}
```

Answer (score 3):

The backwards slash is the escape character in Java.  You need to use two backslashes `\\` to include a single backslash in the regex.

Try:

```
"\"\\w*&&[\\p{Punct}]\"["+sepChar+"]\"\\w*&&[\\p{Punct}]\""
```

Comment: @Wolfchamane - yes you are.  You are trying to include a single forward slash to escape the 'w' ... for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Thanks to @kevin-bowersox for the help.

It seems that Oracle has done a great job improving Java with version 7.
With this code:

```
File file = new File(someFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
  //todo
}
```

If your file has been formatted with a constant patern, for example:

```
"TEXTVALUE":"TEXTVALUE":"TEXTVALUE"
```

It reads:

```
"TEXTVALUE-->TEXTVALUE-->TEXTVALUE"
```

where '-->' stands for tabs ('\t')

So, at the end, my solution is:

```
public ArrayList getSplittedTextFromFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
  ArrayList<String[]> ret = null;
  if (!filePath.isEmpty()){
    File input = new File(filePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
      String[] aSplit = line.split("\\t");
      if (ret == null)
        ret = new ArrayList<>();
      ret.add(aSplit);
    }//while
  }//fi
}//fnc
```